# Resize image at run time php

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

How can i preview an image on the run time?I have the uploader script and re size functionality.But image is not showing at the run time.I dont want to save iamge.Just resize and show at the run time.Image must show from memory not from directory .I was trying something like this :

```
    if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] == 0)
    {  
     $theImageToResize=$_FILES['myfile']['name'];

     $afterResize=Resize($theImageToResize);

     echo $theImageToResize.'---->image after resize';
    }
```

[just want to show image from the memory.Not from Directory];

Server Side Code :

```
  $savefolder = 'images'; //upload dir  
  $max_size = 35000;    //in bytes  

  // image types
  $allowtype = array('bmp', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png');
  $res = '';
  // if is received a valid file
  if (isset ($_FILES['myfile'])) {


 $type = end(explode(".", strtolower($_FILES['myfile']['name'])));
 if (in_array($type, $allowtype)) {

if ($_FILES['myfile']['size']<=$max_size*1000) {

  if ($_FILES['myfile']['error'] == 0) {

    $thefile = $savefolder . "/" . $_FILES['myfile']['name'];

    $theImageToResize=$_FILES['myfile']['name'];


      header('Content-type: image/jpeg');

      $res = '<img src="'.$theImageToResize.'" />';


      }
    }
    else { $res = 'The file <b>'. $_FILES['myfile']['name']. '</b> exceeds max Size           <i>'. $max_size. 'KB</i>'; }
 }
                else { $res = 'The file <b>'. $_FILES['myfile']['name']. '</b> has not an allowed File Tyle..'; }
           }


          $res = urlencode($res);
         echo '<body onload="parent.doneloading(\''.$res.'\')"></body>';
```

Comment: If I were you, I would do this with javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the *binary data* that comprises the image in hand, you can use [a data URI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme) to echo an `<img>` tag with the image embedded, like this:

```
$imageData = /* binary image data */
$mimeType = 'image/jpg'; // or image/gif or image/png, must be accurate
printf('<img src="data:%s;base64,%s" alt="resized image" />',
        $mimeType, base64_encode($imageData));
```

This allows you to output the resized image as part of a web page. If you want to display *just* the image, you can simply output a suitable header and then echo the binary data:

```
header('Content-type: image/jpg');
echo $imageData;
die;
```

Comment: i am sending image from a form using ajax and the server should show the image simply.I can add the resize and image functionality..but i am not getting any image in the response..

Comment: Please take a look at the code edit for the server side php script

Answer (score 0):

```
$_FILES['myfile']['name']
```

contains file name, not location, use

```
$_FILES['myfile']['tmpname']
```

instead.
To resize read about imagecopyresampled PHP function - theres lot's of tutorials about PHP image resizing. To output the image use imagejpeg or imagepng function - this functions will output your image to browser. Do not forget about proper headers, such as

```
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
```

Comment: i am sending image from a form using ajax and the server should show the image simply.I can add the resize and image functionality..but i am not getting any image in the response..